# firebase repository in .net core 3.1 does not work on the server when i deploy it, and works well locally

Tags: firebase, dependency-injection, cqrs, .net-core-3.1, mediatr

i want to send commend in Firestore using a API .net core 3.1, and i am working using clean architecture. and an CQRS pattern.
like this:

```
namespace SmartRestaurant.Infrastructure.Services
{
    public class FirebaseConfig
    {
        public string BasePath { get; set; }
   
    }

    public class FirebaseRepository : IFirebaseRepository
    {
        readonly string _DataBaseBasepath;
        readonly FirestoreDb _db;
        public FirebaseRepository(IOptions<FirebaseConfig> conf)
        {
            _DataBaseBasepath = conf.Value.BasePath;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_DataBaseBasepath))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("fireBase Path not found in appsettings");
            }
            var pathConfigFile = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "jsonProjectConfogFile.json");
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", pathConfigFile);
            _db = FirestoreDb.Create("^projectName");
        }

        public async Task<T> AddAsync<T>(string path, T data, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                DocumentReference doc = _db.Document(_DataBaseBasepath + "/" + path);
                var objectTosend = getOrderToDictionary(data);
                await doc.SetAsync(objectTosend, null, cancellationToken);
                return data;
            }
            catch (Exception exe)
            {
                throw exe;
            }
             
        }
      
   

        public async Task<T> UpdateAsync<T>(string path, T data, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                DocumentReference doc = _db.Document(_DataBaseBasepath + "/" + path);
                var objectTosend = getOrderToDictionary(data);             
                await doc.UpdateAsync(objectTosend, null, cancellationToken);
                return data;
            }
            catch (Exception exe)
            {
                throw exe;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

that code is in the infrastrecture layer and the interface of this service is in the application layer

```
  public interface IFirebaseRepository
    {
        Task<T> AddAsync<T>(string path,T data,CancellationToken cancellationToken);
        
        Task<T> UpdateAsync<T>(string path,T data, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    }
```

the injection of this service is in the infrastrecture layer like this

```
            services.AddTransient < IFirebaseRepository, FirebaseRepository> ();
```

i  use this service in the application layer like this :

```
  public class OrdersCommandsHandlers : IRequestHandler<CreateOrderCommand, OrderDto>,
        IRequestHandler<UpdateOrderCommand, NoContent>,
      {
        private readonly IApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private readonly IUserService _userService;
        private readonly IFirebaseRepository _fireBase;
        private readonly string CreateAction = "CreateAction";
        private readonly string UpdateAction = "UpdateAction";

        public OrdersCommandsHandlers(IApplicationDbContext context, 
                                    IMapper mapper,
                                    IUserService userService,
                                    IFirebaseRepository fireBase)
        {
            _context = context;
            _mapper = mapper;
            _userService = userService;
            _fireBase = fireBase;
        }

        public async Task<OrderDto> Handle(CreateOrderCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var validator = new CreateOrderCommandValidator();
            var result = await validator.ValidateAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (!result.IsValid) throw new ValidationException(result);

         ....

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

            var orderDto = _mapper.Map<OrderDto>(order);
            orderDto.CurrencyExchange = CurrencyConverter.GetDefaultCurrencyExchangeList(orderDto.TotalToPay, foodBusiness.DefaultCurrency);         
            var path = request.FoodBusinessId + "/Orders/" + orderDto.OrderId;
            await _fireBase.AddAsync(path, orderDto, cancellationToken);
                
          ......

            return _mapper.Map<OrderDto>(newOrder);
        }

       public async Task<NoContent> Handle(UpdateOrderCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var validator = new UpdateOrderCommandValidator();
            var result = await validator.ValidateAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (!result.IsValid) throw new ValidationException(result);

       ......
            var orderDto = _mapper.Map<OrderDto>(order);
            var foodBusiness = await _context.FoodBusinesses.FindAsync(order.FoodBusinessId);
            if (foodBusiness != null)
                orderDto.CurrencyExchange = CurrencyConverter.GetDefaultCurrencyExchangeList(orderDto.TotalToPay, foodBusiness.DefaultCurrency);
            var path = order.FoodBusinessId + "/Orders/" + order.OrderId;
            await _fireBase.UpdateAsync(path,orderDto, cancellationToken);
            
            return default;
        }
```

}

```
when i deploiye this code in the server i have this erreur :

Error constructing handler for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[SmartRestaurant.Application.Orders.Commands.CreateOrderCommand,SmartRestaurant.Application.Common.Dtos.OrdersDtos.OrderDto]. Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub for examples.



i try to using fireStor in the NetCore 3 api with CQRS, and a erreur Appear when i use the hendler that contaie firebase service.
and locally all work well , the probleme appear in the server when i deploie the code.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason of this issues is in the constructor of firebaseService

```
   public FirebaseRepository(IOptions<FirebaseConfig> conf)
        {
            _DataBaseBasepath = conf.Value.BasePath;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_DataBaseBasepath))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("fireBase Path not found in appsettings");
            }
            var pathConfigFile = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "jsonProjectConfogFile.json");
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", pathConfigFile);
            _db = FirestoreDb.Create("^projectName");
        }
```

the conf.Value.BasePath is null in the server because the appsetting.json does not contain the FirebaseConfig section.